# Ajax not work on primefaces selectManyCheckbox with converter

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2, converters, selectmanycheckbox

I'm trying to use primefaces selectManyCheckBox with ajax and converter, but the ajax not fired. If I'm didn't use converter, the ajax can fired. Is there something wrong with my converter?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p:outputLabel value="Atur Grade Pinjaman" for="gradePinjaman"/>        
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="gradePinjaman" value="#{autoInvestController.param.grades}" converter="companyGradeConverter">
        <f:selectItems value="#{autoInvestController.grades}" var="grade" itemLabel="#{grade.id}" itemValue="#{grade}"/>                        
        <p:ajax update="selectAll estimation" listener="#{autoInvestController.valueChange}"/>
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>                
    <p:message for="gradePinjaman"/>
</div>
```

Here is my backing bean code

```
public void valueChange() {     
    if (param.getGrades() != null && !param.getGrades().isEmpty()) {
        checkAll = param.getGrades().size() == grades.size();
        calculateCollectEstimation();
    }
}
```

Here is my converter

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {        
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            PlatformService platformService = (PlatformService) CDI.current().select(PlatformService.class).get();
            Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("id", value);
            CompanyGradeResponse companyGrade = platformService.getCompanyGrade(param).get(0);                
            return companyGrade;
        } catch (EndpointException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }            
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {        
    if (value != null) {
        return ((CompanyGradeResponse) value).getId();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think my converter work well, but why the ajax won't fired when i check the checkbox?

Thanks

Comment: With 99% certainty, your problem is solved by one of the bullets mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value. And did you try with a plain jsf `h:selectManyCheckbox`?

Comment: _"I think my converter work well, "_ You can always try without ajax... do make **sure** your converter works...

Comment: No, I didn't try with plain jsf...Ok, i will try without ajax to make sure my converter is working well..As soon as i will update the result

Comment: Btw what do u mean by "You can always try without ajax" to make sure the converter works? method "getAsObject" only called when I use ajax right? I already debug my application and "getAsObject" return the right object

Comment: thank you for your clue...It turn out JSF will perform equal operation between the converter and data on page...The equal operation failed so ajax not fired. So I override the equal method then the ajax success triggered...Thank you very much

Comment: See... This is debugging... creating a [mcve]... **always** do this... Simplify, remove code etc...

Comment: But an 'equal' operation between converter and data on the page? Where? What was your error then?

Comment: first on the p:ajax i update the p:message element then error message show says "validation failed". It looks like when i click the check box, the getAsObject will triggered then equal operation perform between return from getAsObject with object from the check box. I add override method equal on the CompanyGradeResponse object

Comment: @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CompanyGradeResponse other = (CompanyGradeResponse) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id);
    }

Comment: If i didn't override equals method, the return always false